# Not able to input login ID and Password to Bank's Website

Tags: html, excel, vba

I have managed to compile the below mentioned code.
I want to extend my coding further, as for now this coding takes me to my bank's website.

But I'm not able to figure out how do I put my banking login id and password to the bank's website through VBA coding. I also want my code to first click on Corporate Login button and then proceed to input Login ID and Password.

I have also attached an image of the bank's website for reference.

[image]

```
Sub TDS_Autofill()
Dim IE As Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://onlineservices.tin.egov-nsdl.com/etaxnew/tdsnontds.jsp"
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

Set DOC = IE.document
DOC.parentWindow.execScript "sendRequest(281)", "JavaScript"

Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop


If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("n2").Value = "Company" Then
DOC.getElementById("0020").Click
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("n2").Value = "Non Company" Then
DOC.getElementById("0021").Click
End If



If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("p2").Value = "(200) TDS/TCS Payable by Taxpayer" Then
DOC.getElementById("200").Click
ElseIf ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("p2").Value = "(400) TDS/TCS Regular Assessment" Then
DOC.getElementById("400").Click
End If


IE.document.querySelector("select.form-control").selectedIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("s2").Value
DOC.querySelector("#div_nature_error .form-control").FireEvent "onchange"



DOC.getElementById("NetBanking").Click

DOC.getElementById("NetBank_Name_c").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("u2").Value
DOC.querySelector("#NetBank_Name_c").FireEvent "onchange"


DOC.getElementsByName("TAN")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("b2").Value

IE.document.querySelector("select[name=AssessYear]").selectedIndex = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("m2").Value


DOC.getElementsByName("Add_Line1")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("c2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_Line2")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("d2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_Line3")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("e2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_Line4")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("f2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_Line5")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("g2").Value


IE.document.querySelector("select[name=Add_State]").selectedIndex = 21


DOC.getElementsByName("Add_PIN")(1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("i2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_EMAIL")(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("j2").Value

DOC.getElementsByName("Add_MOBILE")(0).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Challan AutoFill").Range("K2").Value


DOC.getElementsByName("captchaText")(0).Value = InputBox("Captcha:")

DOC.querySelector("#Submit").Click
   
   
Do While IE.Busy
Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
        
DOC.getElementById("consentCheck").Click
        
DOC.getElementById("Submit").Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Banks make it exceedingly difficult to automate things like this for a reason. Even if you can get something working today, don't expect it to work tomorrow.

Comment: @braX So it means that this cannot be automated ?

Comment: Consider it would be easy to automate: What would prevent a script to find a valid login via brute force? And how do you want to prevent that someone sneaks into your code to steal the credentials?

Comment: My point is that banking login is something that should not be automated. What is the reason you want to automate it? Don't you realize the security risk in doing such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to secure your credentials in VBA. You are storing your password in plaintext. Never do this for something like banking.

To automate the login process you want to use a tool made for that purpose. Use password manager software to securely store the password. Most modern password managers have a form autofill function that will login automatically.

You could make some automation to run after you are logged in but I wouldn't recommend using VBA for this purpose. There are web libraries made for this purpose so you don't have to write it from scratch. If you use a Python web library you can easily pull data from an Excel spreadsheet with code that is no more difficult to write than VBA.

Comment: I see this just like you and braX. But out of curiosity I tested if it works. In the end I didn't manage to do it. To access the corporate login page from the bank's homepage is easy. Setting the CorporateID and the LoginID also works. But with my knowledge the password cannot be entered automatically. As braX writes, a lot has been done to prevent automation.

Comment: Ok, I have found a (ultimately simple) way to set the password. But for the security reasons mentioned above, it doesn't seem to make sense to show how to do it. I would never deposit my access data to my bank account in plain text in a VBA code myself. Apart from that, a two-factor authentication is mandatory for all banks in Germany.

Comment: @Zwenn that is why I said the automation program can only be ran after you log in securely.

Comment: I agree with that in banking questions.